# Is there any possibility to establish a SSH tunneling from the server using the postgresql to the client

Tags: postgresql, server, ssh-tunnel

I have one server machine where PostgreSQL and SSH server is installed. I have another client machine from where i want to connect to the PostgreSQL on the server machine in a secure way. I used SSH tunnel which is working.

I tried to connect the client with server using:

```
$ ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 user@Host -N -f
```

It is working. But now I am thinking whether it is possible to start the ssh tunneling from the server side. It means run a ssh command on server machine so that I get a more secure connection

Comment: Why don't you set `ssl = on` and use PostgreSQL's built-in SSL support?

Comment: Perhaps a reverse tunnel like `ssh -R 3307:localhost:3306 user@ClientMachine` ? (It's been a while since I did a reverse, but I think that's the right idea and format).

Comment: @JNevill Yes, I have tried the remote port forwarding by using `ssh -R 3306:localhost:3307 user@ClientMachine` which did not work. 3306 should be the port number of database on the remote server and 3307 is the port number on the client. It did not work and the sshd log told me that `error: bind: Address already in use` which is easy to understand that 3306 is the database port number which has been used by PostgreSQL database on server (sorry, it actually should be 5432, let's just use 3306 as an example.). So, to my understand, It is not possible to run a ssh tunneling on the server machine?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you, this should be an option. But the intention was that we can start this kind of connection on the server machine. So the administrator on the server side can control this connection and stop that whenever needed.

Comment: You could control that in the classical way with entries in `pg_hba.conf`. That would even be more convenient.